# NSLabel: output of leading zeros?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I write (using leading zeros)

```
(@"%d",9);
```

to be 00009
using a method that may exist in NS?

thanks

Comment: Your question uses NSLog, but the title mentions NSLabel. Which is it?

Comment: both NSLog and NSLabel, but I believe your solution, that was posted, works for both... repost and I check box it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%05d`. You can use this with `NSLog` or with `stringWithFormat:`.

Answer (score 9):

@LaC has a correct answer.  But here's an interesting question: What if you don't know how many 0s you want?

Never fear, you can do this!

```
int numberOfZeros = 5;
NSLog(@"%0*d", numberOfZeroes, 9);
```

The "*" tells it to look for an extra `int` specifying the padding length.  Neat, huh?